# Pass properties (attribute directives) to template

Tags: angular, attributes

let's say I have some attribute directives: directive1, directive2 and directive3.
I use them like this

```
<someComponent directive1 directive3></someComponent>
<otherComponent></otherComponent>
```

I use someComponent very often with otherComponent and I'd like to wrap them in wrapperComponent. I'd like wrapperComponent to have just config property, to which I can pass all config for someComponent and otherComponent, including directives.

How can I pass attribute directives or set them from component, like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
<someComponent {{config.directives}}></someComponent>
<otherComponent></otherComponent>
`
})
classWrapperComponent {
  @Input() config;
}
```

usage:

```
<wrapperComponent [config]="config"></wrapperComponent>
```

Comment: Directives can **only** be added statically by adding HTML **statically** to a components template that matches directives selectors. There is no way to add/remove directives in any dynamic way.

Comment: Gunter is right, to understand why, read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)